# EntityDescription value ForUndefinedKey this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key "KEY"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to save NSDictionary to core data with the following code.

```
NSManagedObject *myObject = [NSEntityDescription
                                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"HomeDB"
                                inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:dataDict forKey:@"pod_casts"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[archiver release];
[myObject setValue:data forKey:@"podcasts"];
[data release];

[self saveChanges];
```

And also trying to retrieve the NSDictionary from core data with the following code

```
NSEntityDescription *p = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HomeDB" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSData *data1 = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[p valueForKey:@"podcasts"]];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data1];
NSDictionary *dbData=[[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"pod_casts"] retain];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
[unarchiver release];
[data1 release];
```

What is wrong in this? Help me.

I have created the Entity "HomeDB" with one attribute "podcasts" of type "Binary"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entityForName:...` returns an `NSEntityDescription`, you seem to think it is going to return the `HomeDB` object you created in the first code snippet.

To retrieve a managed object from core data, you need to use a fetch request, something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"HomeDB"];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

The results array will contain all `HomeDB` objects in your context.

Assuming you only have one, then you'd get it out like this:

```
NSManagedObject *homeDB = [results lastObject];
NSData *data = [homeDB valueForKey:@"podcasts"];
```

From this point you can continue with the `data` object as you were in your second code snippet.

Comment: I am saving the data as NSData which is also encoded. I need this NSData as response then I have to decode it.

This NSFetchRequest will returns the result as NSArray.

Can you help me?

Comment: as I said in the answer, the array will contain all of the HomeDB objects in your context. I don't know how many you have or which one you want. But you can get one of them out using something like `[results lastObject]`. This will give you an actual `HomeDB` object which you can then get the data from using `valueForKey:@"podcasts"`